# ASP.NET - How to propagate events with nested user controls

Tags: asp.net, events, delegates, delegation

I have nested controls on a page. Ex:

```
Page 
  -ChildControl1 (of type AllOfMyItems)
      -ChildControl2 (of type ListOfItems)
         -ChildControl3 (of type MyItem <- this one fires event)
```

When child control raises an event, I want page to handle that event. What is a good way to do this?

[Events and delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) seem like a good idea to use here.

So I'm trying to do the following on Page_Init of my Page:

```
 MyItem.SomethingHappened += doStuff();
```

what is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have direct access to ChildControl2 from your page and thats your problem.

One option is to bubble the event from one UserControl to it's parent UserControl and so on until your page handles the ParentControl.SomethingHappened event. This way is recommended  if the usercontrols aren't always nested like in this example.